# Retrofit dynamic url

Tags: android, retrofit2

how can annotate retrofit method to pass "&page=1" and "&per_page" parameters in the following link: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris&page=1&per_page=10
I want to be able to change these parameters at runtime.
 I figured out how to annotate query param "tetris", but I couldn't find it for "&page=1" and "&per_page" parameters. Here is my retrofit interface:

```
String BASE_URL = "https://api.github.com/";

@Headers("User-Agent: useragent")
@GET("search/repositories")
Call<GitHubRepo> searchRepos(@Query("q") String searchParam);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are also query parameters.

The first query parameter in an URL is always added using a '?', and all following query parameters are added using a '&'. This is a standard for URLs, not just in Android, but everywhere.

Retrofit will take care of correctly using '?' and '&' in the right places for you, so simply add all the query parameters you want, just like you added them in your current setup, and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
@GET("search/repositories")
Call<GitHubRepo> searchRepos(
    @Query("page") Integer page),
    @Query("per_page") Integer perPage
)
```